# How to add different set of parameters to factory method design pattern to achieve proper design

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory

I have a scenario where two different classes have many properties and one different property. How do I use factory design pattern or should I not use it?
Internal private methods of these sub classes make use of these properties.

```
public class RunsValidator  
{  
     //Few common properties  
     public int DataSegmentID { get; set; }  
     public int AttributeOffset { get; set; }  
}

public class ProductAttributeRunValidator : RunsValidator  
{

    public ProductAttributeRunValidator(string productNames)
    {
       this.ProdNames = productNames;
    }
}

public class CategoryAttributeRunValidator : RunsValidator  
{  

     public CategoryAttributeRunValidator(int orgIDs) : base()  
          {  
            this.totalOrgIDs = orgIDs;  
          }  

}
```

//Factory implementation

```
public class RunAttributeFactory  
{     

    public static RunsValidator GetRunValidator(string type, string productNames, int orgIds)  
     {  
      RunsValidator runValidator = null;  
      if(type == "Product")  
      {   
           runValidator = new ProductAttributeRunValidator(productNames);  
      }  
      else if (type == "Category")  
      {  
           runValidator = new CategoryAttributeRunValidator(orgIds);  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          runValidator = null;  
      }  
      return runValidator;  
    }  
}
```

In the client code, I have access to variables that should be sent as parameters (productNames, orgIds and type) to the Factory method. I would like to access the returned runValidator in many places in the client code as it needs to be set only once based on the type.

Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you even using a factory at all? Why can't the client just use the object constructors directly?

Comment: I want to remove multiple occurences of below code whenever I want to access the base type. If there are any more new sub-types, I want them to be easily manageable, so I am trying to keep the if -else logic at only one location.

if(type == "Product")  
      {   
           runValidator = new ProductAttributeRunValidator(productNames);  
      }  
      else if (type == "Category")  
      {  
           runValidator = new CategoryAttributeRunValidator(orgIds);  
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that the client will have to know the type of the output to know what parameters to pass in, and that you have no re-usable code between the two types, I see no value from a "generic" factory pattern here.  I would either have two factories (if you even *need* a factory for either type), or let the client call the type constructor directly.

Comment: I have a common method in the base type that is not included in the original question. That common method will internally call other methods that make use of these different properties in sub classes.